# How to compare node in depth on select element type xquery, search for nodes with matching child elements?

Tags: xquery

Let's say i will have 2 xml documents
xml1

```
<req>
    <a name="1">
        <a name="2"/>
    </a>
</req>
```

and
xml2

```
<r>
    <b id="1">
        <a name="1">
            <a name="2"/>
        </a> 
    </b>
    <b id="2">
        <a name="3">
            <a name="4">
                <a name="5"/>
            </a>
        </a> 
    </b>
</r>
```

What i want to do is use xml1 as list of required nodes for searched for element to contain. As in, i want to return only those "b" elements that contain only those child elements "a" that are specified in xml1 and no others (it can still contain other elements with different name), But what i am trying to figure out how to ensure, that every child element of the "a" is also specified "a" and no other.

Basically so that i would find only those "b" elements whos "a" elements are specified in xml1 and have exactly same "a" child elements (any other element can be ignored)

```
for $r in $xml2/r/b
where (every $a 
        in $r/a 
        satisfies $a/@name = $xml1/req/a/@name)
return $r
```

Is what i tried so far, but if i understand correctly, this should only check the very first layer

Edit: And just in case, better specification for the searching rule: The "b" node is a result node if and only if it contains all and only the "a" nodes specified in xml1, and two "a" nodes are identical if they have same name and same "a" node children.

Edit 2:
For clarification, following two "b" are equal

```
<r>
    <b id="1">
        <a name="1">
            <a name="2"/>
        </a> 
    </b>
</r>
```

and

```
<r>
    <b id="1">
        <a name="1">
            <a name="2"/>
            <d/>
        </a> 
        <c/>
    </b>
</r>
```

Comment: If your are not bound to finding a recursive solution, you might want to have a look at fn:deep-equal.

Comment: I corrected it. Solution doesn't have to be recursive, i just didn't know how else to describe it. But i only need them to be equal on the "a" type elements, they can have any other child elements that are not the same, as long as the "a" ones match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution assumes that there may be multiple `a` elements on each level, and it assumes that the order of these elements must be identical:

```
declare variable $xml1 := <req>...</req>;
declare variable $xml2 := <r>...</r>;

declare function local:deep-equal-a($xml, $find) {
  let $xas := $xml/a, $fas := $find/a
  return count($xas) = count($fas) and (
    every $test in for-each-pair($xas, $fas, function($xa, $fa) {
      $xa/@name = $fa/@name and local:deep-equal-a($xa, $fa)
    }) satisfies $test
  )
};

for $b in $xml2/b
where local:deep-equal-a($b, $xml1)
return $b
```

If there will be at most one `a` element per level, the query can be simplified:

```
declare function local:deep-equal-a($xml, $find) {
  let $xa := $xml/a, $fa := $find/a
  return not($xa and $fa) or
    $xa/@name = $fa/@name and local:deep-equal-a($xa, $fa)
};
```

Comment: I can't use inline functions (not supported), so i reworked it into `declare function local:cmp-pair($xa, $fa) { return $xa/@name = $fa/@name and local:deep-equal-a($xa, $fa) };` However this gives me an error "XPST0003: expected "}", found "$"

Comment: Did you choose Solution 1 oder 2? Do you mean that for-each-pair is not supported? Which XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: I used the first example. Query processor is Saxon and it throws errors on higher order functions.

Comment: Try to replace the function call with `(for $c in 1 to count($xas) let $xa := $xas[$c] let $fa := $fas[$c] return $xa/@name = $fa/@name and local:deep-equal-a($xa, $fa))`